# How can I hardcode CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX only for a certain COMPONENT?

Tags: cmake

Please see the below minimal example:

```
add_library(foo SHARED foo.cpp)

install(
  TARGETS foo
  DESTINATION .
  COMPONENT python)

add_custom_target(
  install-python
  DEPENDS foo
  COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_COMPONENT=python -P
          "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/cmake_install.cmake")
```

Is there a way to hardcode `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` in the CMakeLists somewhere to a certain path, e.g. `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/python`, only for a certain install COMPONENT, e.g `python`? In other words, I want to be able to do `cmake ..`, `make install-python`, `make install`, instead of something like `cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$(pwd)/python ..`, `make install-python`, `cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..`, `make install` in order to achieve the same thing. Is that possible?

On a side note, the main reason why I want to use `install` here is because in the real situation, if I simply use an `add_custom_command` to copy `foo` from `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}` to `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/python`, there isn't an easy way to get rid of all the `LC_RPATH` listed in `otool -l ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/libFoo.so`. There isn't a way to delete all rpaths with install_name_tool. The closest we got is `install_name_tool -delete_rpath` but it requires the exact rpath to delete to be known. Using `install` solves this problem because the installed `Foo` will only contain `LC_RPATH` specified by the `INSTALL_RPATH` target property.

Comment: note that hardcoding `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` can be overridden via commandline with `--prefix`, which can lead to unexpected behaviour.

Comment: if you're going to hardcode by component, why not just hardcode the `DESTINATION` for the `install` calls for those components?

Comment: "I simply use an `add_custom_command` to copy `foo` from `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}` to `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/python`, there isn't an easy way to get rid of all the `LC_RPATH`..." - If you want to build the library in `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/python` instead of `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}`, then adjust its [LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html) property. If you don't want CMake to add RPATH to the library, then set corresponding properties too (https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/cmake/RPATH-handling).

Comment: @starball is there a way to hardcode the install `DESTINATION` so that `${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}` isn't involved? If I change the `DESTINATION` from `.` to `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/python`, isn't the install destination still going to be `${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/python`?

Comment: @Tsyvarev in the real situation I still need `Foo` with the build tree rpaths so it can link to it's dependent shared libs and run tests correctly, the copy to python folder only happens when `make python-wheel` is called, where `Foo` and all it's dependent shared libs are copied to the python folder, and ideally all build tree rpath stripped away and `@loader_path`  added as the only LC_RPATH via install_name_tool.

Comment: @starball I just realized that there’s a way to hardcode the install destination without involving CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX! If you turn your comment into an answer, I will accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`cmake --install`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#install-a-project) allows you to specify `--prefix <prefix>` and `--component <component>` arguments. Ex. with what you said you want to achieve, I'd first try to do this:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..
cmake --install . --prefix $(pwd)/python --component python
cmake --install .
```

The above would install the python component twice to both locations. I think if you want to be really exact, you'd need to specify all components except for python in the last command.

---

If you're going to hardcode `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`, which I'm pretty sure should be an absolute path by component, I'd suggest to just hardcode the `DESTINATION` for the install calls for those components to whatever absolute path you want. If you need to do anything different between various platforms, see [the platform generator expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#platform).

Note that there are various mechanisms in CMake for manipulating `RPATH`s. Just take a look at the [property listing](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-properties.7.html) and [variable listing](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-variables.7.html) and search for those whose names include "RPATH". See also [the related wiki page](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/cmake/RPATH-handling).