# CMake: Why does BUILD_INTERFACE have no effect on target_link_options?

Tags: cmake

Please see the below minimal example:

```
add_library(Foo SHARED foo.cpp foo.h)
target_link_options(Foo PUBLIC $<BUILD_INTERFACE:-Wl,-rpath,/aaa/bbb>)
install(TARGETS Foo LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install
                            COMPONENT install-foo)
add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/libFoo.dylib
  DEPENDS Foo
  COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_COMPONENT=install-foo -P
          "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/cmake_install.cmake")
add_custom_target(install-foo ALL
                  DEPENDS ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/libFoo.dylib)
```

For some reason after `make install-foo`, `otool -l install/libFoo.dylib` still shows `/aaa/bbb` in LC_RPATH, it's as if the `BUILD_INTERFACE` in `target_link_options` does nothing. Shouldn't `/aaa/bbb` only exist in `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/libFoo.dylib` and not `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/libFoo.dylib` in the LC_RPATH?

Comment: You seem to think that when use `BUILD_INTERFACE` and/or `INSTALL_INTERFACE`, a target will be compiled/linked **twice**. This is not true: a target is compiled/linked **once**, taking into account `BUILD_INTERFACE` only. The `BUILD_INTERFACE` is skipped only when create an export file with `install(EXPORT)` and it **affects only on that file**. That is, consumers of your installed project will see empty **CMake property** [INTERFACE_LINK_OPTIONS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/INTERFACE_LINK_OPTIONS.html). But installed library file has RPATH `/aaa/bbb` embedded into it.

Comment: CMake is able to strip some RPATH settings from the library file upon installation. But this affects only those RPATH settings which has been added via special RPATH-related properties. This is described in the https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/cmake/RPATH-handling. (I have already provided that link to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76562152/how-can-i-hardcode-cmake-install-prefix-only-for-a-certain-component)).

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks for the explanation, is there a way to achieve what I want to achieve? Meaning the dylib in the build tree will have RPATH `/aaa/bbb`, but the installed dylib will have RPATH `/aaa/bbb` stripped away?

Comment: Why do you need RPATH for your library in the build tree? If your library is linked with some other one by using `target_link_libraries`, then CMake automatically adds required RPATH. When a library is installed, CMake will drop that RPATH.

Comment: @Tsyvarev in the real situation, `Foo` is linking to an imported library `Bar`, but the `IMPORTED_LOCATION` is set to where `libBar.tbd` is, and in order to find the `Bar` dylib in runtime, the `INTERFACE_LINK_OPTIONS` is set to `-Wl,-rpath,<path-to-the-folder-of-libBar.dylib>`.  This rpath to `libBar.dylib` is not needed in the scenario of `install` because I will be copying `libBar.dylib` to where `libFoo.dylib` is during the `install` and I will be setting the `INSTALL_RPATH` for `Foo` to `@loader_path`

Comment: You may set target property [BUILD_RPATH](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/BUILD_RPATH.html) to the desired directory. This directory will be used when building the project, but will be stripped when installing it.

Comment: @Tsyvarev that's a new idea that I never thought of, but ideally where to look for `libBar.dylib` should be set from `Bar` instead of `Foo`, I wish there's something like `INTERFACE_BUILD_RPATH` that we can use